# Can PHP Read CSV File While moving process is not finished?

Tags: php, csv

I am using crontab to process csv files(Read, and insert data to DATABASE) and job is running after every single minute. And the is moving by multiple network users.

This is a linux server and users are using XP AND may be win7. They may use filezilla,flashfxp or directly access the directory via ftp folder (//serviver/directory).

I  came to know that while a file is moving or transferring  to a  directory is moving by byte to byte. so my question is while the moving process is not finished can PHP read that file?.

expecting your valuable answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving a file is done by copying the individual bytes and deleting the original only if that move is done from one disk partition to a different disk partition. In that case, the file can be read as soon as it is visible in the destination folder. It may be that the file is not yet complete at that point.

If you move the file to a different folder within the same disk partion, no copying is done and the whole file can be read as soon as the file is visible in the destination folder.

Comment: i think you didn't mentioned about network user. they may use filezilla or flashfxp or accessing \\server\directory(shared). they will do just drag and drop. what will happen in that case?